# Creating Generator object from record list within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm trying to create generator object for the list of records with the data from mysql database, so I'm passing the mysql cursor object to the function as parameter.

My issue here is if the "if block" containing yield records is commented then cust_records function works perfectly fine but if I uncomment the line then the function is not working.

Not sure if this is not the way to yield the list object in Python 3

My code so far:

```
def cust_records(result_set) :

    block_id = None
    records = []
    i = 0
    for row in result_set :
        records.append((row['id'], row, smaller_ids))

    if records :
        yield records
```

Comment: Do you want to `yield` the list object or `yield from` the list object?

Comment: if the yield records in the last line is commented - nothing should work because you'll have a "hanging" if condition without a body

Comment: @moses i am looking to yield the list object

Comment: @min2bro why use `yield` at all, then? It will *always be a generator with a single element*, why not just `return` the list?

Comment: @alfasin if i comment the last line and the if block above it then everything works perfectly fine, I'm looking to yirld the record list which i'm creating just above it

Comment: For what it's worth, building the full list and then yielding from it kind of defeats the purpose of a generator.

Comment: @min2bro what about `return iter(records)` ?

Comment: @Szabolcs Is it a generator object?

Comment: @min2bro commenting out the last *two* lines is not the same as commenting out only the last line! please improve your question by making it accurate. Further, "everything works alright" is not clear - a function that used to return a value is now not returning anything - how is that "alright" ?

Comment: @min2bro please post a MCVE and clearly explain 1/ what you mean by "does not work" (if you have an exception please post it with the full traceback etc, else explain what you expected and what you get instead) and 2/ what you're __really__ trying to do here (what is the problem you are trying to solve with this code).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of generators is lazy evaluation, so storing all records in a list and yielding the list makes no sense at all. If you want to retain lazy evalution (which is IMHO preferable, specially if you have to work on arbitrary datasets that might get huge), you want to yield each record, ie:

```
def cust_records(result_set) :
    for row in result_set :
        yield (row['id'], row, smaller_ids)


# then
def example():
   cursor.execute(<your_sql_query_here>)      
   for record in cust_records(cursor):
       print(record)
```

else (if you *really* want to consume as much memory as possible) just male `cust_record` a plain function:

```
def cust_records(result_set) :
    records = []
    for row in result_set :
        records.append((row['id'], row, smaller_ids))
    return records
```